# Get alerted whenever someone uses your Mac?

Tags: macos, security, mac-mini, osx-server

I have a dedicated Mac Mini in a colocation that I access via Remote Desktop. I trust the colocation provider, but I don't trust my password is secure enough. Without resorting to a more secure password, is there an app that alerts me via E-mail or Push Notification via OS X server whenever the mouse moves on the Mac?

Comment: You might get suggestions over at Software Recommendations (http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) as well

Comment: What about Apple script?

Answer (score 1):

I found an [article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2028403/dont-get-apple-picked-how-to-protect-your-mac-from-theft-in-public-places.html) on Macworld that suggested two apps: 
[Hidden](http://hiddenapp.com/) 
[Undercover](http://orbicule.com/undercover/mac/)

Their pricing is quite different. Undercover charges $49 for unlimited use on 1 device, while Hidden charges $2.50/month for 3 devices. If you want a free option, I think [Mackeeper](http://mackeeper.com)'s Anti-Theft feature is free, but I don't trust them.

**Update**: I found a free app called [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) which looks much more legit than Mackeeper.

Comment: These tools aren't exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for an alert system that will alert me every time the mouse moves (once an hour max).

Comment: @Ninja I don't remember if Cisco Meraki Systems Manager (free) allows this, but the programs I suggested can preform what you want them to do if you mark the device as "lost"